# Why delete in vector of instances subsitution?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, delete-operator

This is not a practical question but it is only for educational curiosity.

In some forum I've just found this piece of code:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> myvec;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  myvec.push_back(new MyClass( foo1 ));
}

// somewhere in the code inside a particular if statement
MyClass* replacement = new MyClass( foo2 );
delete myvec[0];
myvec[0] = replacement;
```

I have a vector of instances of MyClass and somewhere in the code I have to do substitution of some instances with others.

Why do I have to call the delete? Is replacing the pointer not enough?

### WHAT I'VE LEARNED:

- there are some devil outside called [memory leaks](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) [@larsmans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499340/433685)
- "for each call to new you should have a corresponding call to delete somewhere in the code." [@Dirk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9499479/433685)
- I can use shared pointer.. [@CashCow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500177/433685)
- I can use valgrind

Comment: A better question: why store pointers in the first place?

Comment: and to find leaks just run your program with `valgrind --leak-check=full ...`.

Comment: This is very practical question. With memory management errors you can put your team into nasty troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard container of pointers will never delete the target of any pointers that it contains. It has no way of knowing that they point to objects created with `new` - they could have been created with `new[]` (in which case `delete[]` is needed), or they could be pointers to static or automatic objects, which must not be deleted, or there may be something else responsible for deleting them.

Usually, you would store objects in a container, rather than pointers. If you really need pointers (perhaps because the objects need to be different types), and you really need those pointers to manage the object lifetime, consider using a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr`, which automatically deletes its target, or `boost::ptr_vector` if that is not available.

Otherwise, if you really must use raw pointers to manage object lifetimes, you'll have to be careful to use `delete` yourself at the right time. In that case, a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) can help to identify the inevitable memory leaks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't `delete` the original `MyClass`, it will stay around but be inaccessible, since you wiped the pointer to it. That's a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Note that if any of the `new` expressions in the initial allocation (except the first one) throws, then you're leaking the previously allocated elements.

All of this can be avoided by not using a `vector` of pointers but a simple `std::vector<MyClass>`, or by using smart pointers if you really have to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly free the memory otherwise it remains allocated, but inaccessible. This is not Java or C# where the garbage collector will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest issues within C++ is what type to store in a vector of objects.

- You can store a vector of instances if the objects are default-constructible, copyable and assignable, but if the copying and assigning are expensive then so might storing them in a vector. Also if you retrieve a value to modify, you need to retrieve a reference. But if the vector changes whilst you hold this reference, your reference could be invalidated
- You can store a vector of pointers, as you have. Then you need to manage the lifetime of the pointers as the vector won't.
- You can store a vector of `shared_ptr` and this is commonly done. It is not ideal as the ownership of the object is presumably in the vector. You won't get into trouble doing it but it's not the most perfect way to deal with a large collection of objects.
- boost provides a special vector to pointer that manages the lifetimes for you. Can be a good alternative
- New C++11 will allow vectors of moveable objects and I think vector of unique_ptr may permitted too (vector of auto_ptr is not).

It is rather subjective but the ideal is to typedef to a pointer type and then use a vector of that typedef. You can later change the typedef if it suits you. `shared_ptr` will probably do the job for you.

Now it ends up like this:

```
typedef spns::shared_ptr< MyClass > MyClassPtr; 
      // spns is an alias to the namespace you use for shared_ptr, either std or boost
std::vector<MyClassPtr> myvec;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
{
  myvec.push_back(MyClassPtr( new MyClass( foo1 ));
  // but with C++11 if you still use shared_ptr replace with
 // myvec.push_back( spns::make_shared<MyClass>(foo1) );
}

// somewhere in the code inside a particular if statement
MyClass* replacement = new MyClass( foo2 );
myvec[0] = MyClassPtr( replacement );

 // preferred alternative to above 2 lines
 //  myvec[0].reset( new MyClass(foo2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<MyClass*>` is a vector of pointers. It does not manage the lifetimes of the objects it holds -- it only manages the memory to the array of pointers it represents.

If you do not manage the `delete`s correctly, you will end up with leaks (unless you wind up deleting twice from another error).

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
new MyClass( foo1 )
```

memory is allocated in the heap to store an object of your class MyClass.
This memory stays allocated until you free it yourself using delete.

So for each call to new you should have a corresponding call to delete somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your `vector`, you stored the pointer, pointed to the memory malloced by yourself. If you just replaced one element of vector, the vector does nothing with that memory, maybe some class will free that memory automatically, but vector does not do so. I think you can consider the same condition in a normal array not the vector.